# AWK bash command auto remove whitespaces

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I used AWK command to split a string like this

```
LINE="91345|/2015/01/30/Launch Trailer - Might  Magic Heroes III HD Edition(1).mp4"
```

Between Might and Magic have two whitespaces

And I run command

```
video_path=`echo $LINE|awk -F$separator '{print $2}'`
```

After running only a single whitespace between Might and Magic

```
/2015/01/30/Launch Trailer - Might Magic Heroes III HD Edition(1).mp4
```

How can I keep two whitespaces in string I recieved.

Sory for my bad English :( !!!

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes in `echo` statement to preserve all whitespaces:

```
video_path=$(echo "$LINE" | awk -F "$separator" '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo $LINE` should be `echo "$LINE"`:

```
video_path=$(echo "$LINE" | awk -F$separator '{print $2}')
```